# Python Replace Whole Values in Dataframe String and Not Substrings

Tags: python, regex, pandas, replace

I am trying to replace strings in a dataframe if the whole string equals another string.  I do not want to replace substrings.

So:

If I have df:

```
 Index  Name       Age
   0     Joe        8
   1     Mary       10
   2     Marybeth   11
```

and I want to replace "Mary" when the whole string matches "Mary" with "Amy" so I get

```
 Index  Name       Age
   0     Joe        8
   1     Amy        10
   2     Marybeth   11
```

I'm doing the following:

```
df['Name'] = df['Name'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('Mary','Amy'))
```

My understanding from searching around is that the defaults of `replace` set `regex=False` and `replace` *should* look for the whole value in the dataframe to be "Mary".  Instead I'm getting this result:

```
 Index  Name       Age
   0     Joe        8
   1     Amy        10
   2     Amybeth   11
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Explanation:**

When you apply it like this - you are working with strings, not with Pandas Series:

```
In [42]: df['Name'].apply(lambda x: print(type(x)))
<class 'str'>  # <---- NOTE
<class 'str'>  # <---- NOTE
<class 'str'>  # <---- NOTE
Out[42]:
0    None
1    None
2    None
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

It's the same as:

```
In [44]: 'Marybeth'.replace('Mary','Amy')
Out[44]: 'Amybeth'
```

**Solution:**

Use [Series.replace(to_replace=None, value=None, inplace=False, limit=None, regex=False, method='pad', axis=None)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) properly (without `Series.apply()`) - per default (`regex=False`) it will replace whole strings - as you expect it to work:

```
In [39]: df.Name.replace('Mary','Amy')
Out[39]:
0         Joe
1         Amy
2    Marybeth
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

you can explicitly specify `regex=True`, this will replace substrings:

```
In [40]: df.Name.replace('Mary','Amy', regex=True)
Out[40]:
0        Joe
1        Amy
2    Amybeth
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

NOTE: [Series.str.replace(pat, repl, n=-1, case=None, flags=0)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) doesn't have `regex` parameter - it's always treats `pat` and `repl` as RegEx's:

```
In [41]: df.Name.str.replace('Mary','Amy')
Out[41]:
0        Joe
1        Amy
2    Amybeth
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 6):

`replace` + `dict` is the way to go (With DataFrame, you are using `Series.str.replace`)

```
df['Name'].replace({'Mary':'Amy'})
Out[582]: 
0         Joe
1         Amy
2    Marybeth
Name: Name, dtype: object
df['Name'].replace({'Mary':'Amy'},regex=True)
Out[583]: 
0        Joe
1        Amy
2    Amybeth
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

Notice they are different

`Series`:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html

`DataFrame`:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use also `loc` to locate instances where the name exactly matches, and then set to the new name.

```
df.loc[df['Name'] == 'Mary', 'Name'] = "Amy"
```