# Python: replace case insensitive flag doesn't work

Tags: python, pandas, replace, ignore-case

In my dataframe I want to replace different ways of representing something with a single consistent string. Examples:

1. Replace [COM, COMMERCIAL] with "Commercial".
2. Replace [FALSE, False, false, NO, No, N] with N and so on.

The list of values to be replaced and the replacement value come from another dataframe and will change as I run through each column in my main dataframe.

The ideal solution that should work is:

```
dfPA[col] = dfPA[col].replace(f'(?i){valold}', key)

where
valold = ['COM', 'COMMERCIAL']
key = 'Commercial'
```

This doesn't work. Maybe because valold is a list. So I tried:

```
for val in valold:
    dfPA[col] = dfPA[col].replace(f'(?i){val}', key)
```

It still doesn't work. Any thoughts?

Note: I CANNOT use `dfPA[col] = dfPA[col].str.replace(valold, key, case=False, regex=False)` because as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48214863/python-replace-whole-values-in-dataframe-string-and-not-substrings) it will replace substrings too. And I then instead of 'Commercial' I see 'ComCom...Commercial'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) or [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) *can* be used. Just make sure the pattern matches the start (`^`) and end (`$`) of the string for whole cell matches.

`str.replace`:

```
for val in valold:
    dfPA[col] = dfPA[col].str.replace(rf'^{val}$', key, case=False, regex=True)
```

`replace`:

```
for val in valold:
    dfPA[col] = dfPA[col].replace(rf'(?i)^{val}$', key, regex=True)
```

*`regex=False` by default for `replace` so the `regex` case insensitivity modifier will not work for replace without setting `regex=True` as it will literally match the characters "(?i)".

---

Sample Data and Output:

```
import pandas as pd

dfPA = pd.DataFrame({
    'col': ['COM', 'COMMERCIAL', 'COmMErCIaL', 'Something else',
            'comical']
})

valold = ['COM', 'COMMERCIAL']
key = 'Commercial'
col = 'col'
for val in valold:
    dfPA[col] = dfPA[col].str.replace(rf'^{val}$', key, case=False, regex=True)

print(dfPA)
```

```
              col
0      Commercial
1      Commercial
2      Commercial
3  Something else
4         comical
```

Comment: Thanks this worked.  I have a few follow-on questions if you can answer:
1. Between ```df[col].str.replace``` and ```df[col].replace``` is one better than the other? 2. Any good resource to understand flags and modifiers?

Comment: 1. I can't say for all cases as size and datatype will greatly determine how long this type of operation takes. However, it appears in my testing that they both have almost exactly the same timings. I'd guess they're implemented very similarly. 2. I only really use `regex` in passing, I'm not a good source for resources on that topic. Sorry.